# How can I stop bots to sign in with google?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have an app with google sign in and seems like some bots are always generating accounts like this: "rickeyroy.16165@gmail.com". It is always "randomname"."randomnumber"@gmail.com

Does someone know how could I stop these bots? I'm using firebase oauth.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Device Id and check for a unique combination of **email + device_id** to identity a user.

```
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString((application.getContentResolver()), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: I don't see how can it stop the bots to sign in

Comment: You might consider integrating Recaptcha for Android